# Кнопки UIButtons в ячейках таблицы UITableViewCell в iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с непониманием как реализовать следующую конструкцию:

> на вьюхе есть таблица, в каждой ячейке
> которой располагаться кнопка, событие
> касания кнопки должно запускать
> функцию и передавать ей параметром
> индексы секции и строки ячейки в
> которой располагалась эта кнопка.

Помогите правильно прописать кнопки и получить нужные индексы

Comment: а почему вы не хотите вместо кнопок использовать метод?

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

для получения секции:

[UITableView numberOfSections]

Comment: потому что по касанию ячейки происходит одно событие, а по касанию кнопки - другое;) мне надо их отдельно обрабатывать и производить разные действия

Comment: Надеюсь мой ответ поможет тебе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ячейки кастомные? Отлично. Смотри:

1.создай сабкласс UIButton (IndexedButton например), добавь в него свойство

```
 @property (nonatomic) NSIndexPath *button_indexPath;
```

В ***IndexedButton.m*** сделай  `@synthesize button_indexPath;`

2.В классе твоей кастомной ячейки в **.h файле** подключаешь этот  IndexedButton:

```
 #import "IndexedButton.h"
```

и кнопку, которую надо нажимать, делаешь не **UIButton**, a
**IndexedButton**:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet IndexedButton *buttonInCell;
```

В **m-файле кастомной ячейки** сделай  `@synthesize buttonInCell;`

Там же ты эту кнопку и добавляешь в ячейку в методе:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{    
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self){
        buttonInCell = [[IndexedButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,30)];
        [self addSubview:buttonInCell];
    // здесь еще твой код
    }
    return self;    
}
```

3.Почти все. Теперь в главном классе, метод
**cellForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath     {
      // тут подключение твоей кастомной ячейки
        if (cell == nil) {
            //Создание ячейки
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault

                                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

          cell.buttonInCell.button_indexPath = indexPath; //присваиваем кнопке значение indexPath
            [cell.buttonInCell addTarget:self action:@selector(MyMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //устанавливаем обработчик для нажатия кнопки

        // здесь еще твой код

        return cell;
    }
```

4.Финиш- метод MyMethod:

```
-(IBAction)MyMethod:(id)sender{
   NSIndexPath *path = [sender button_indexPath]; //извлекаем IndexPath с кнопки.
   //наслаждаемся результатом
   NSLog(@"секция = %i", path.section);
   NSLog(@"ряд = %i", path.row);
}
```

Надеюсь, разъяснил доступно.

Comment: да, подклассы создавал

Answer (score 0):

Создадим сабкласс ячейки:

```
@interface MyButtonedCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^buttonPressedHandler)(void);

@end
```

Не важно как вы создаете ячейку, предположим, что ксиб или сториборд:

```
@implementation MyButtonedCell

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    if (self.buttonPressedHandler)
        self.buttonPressedHandler();
}

@end
```

Далее хорошо знакомый нам метод из `UITableViewDataSource`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellFoRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyButtonedCell *cell = [tableView dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
    /* конфигурим нашу ячейку как обычно  */
    /* создаем слабую ссылку на self для использования внутри блока, избегаем таким образом ритэйн лупа. Этот пункт ОБЯЗАТЕЛЕН К ИСПОЛНЕНИЮ, нельзя так просто взять и ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ self внутри этого блока, только СЛАБУЮ ССЫЛКУ */
    __weak MyTableViewController *self_ = self; 
    cell.buttonPressedHandler = ^{
         /* делаем тут что хотим по нажатию кнопки в ячейке с доступным нам тут indexPath*/
    [self_ doSomethingByPressButtonAtObject: self_.items[indexPath.row]];
    };
    return cell;
}
```